# How to iteral array grab property values which are numeric

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Trying to figure out a way to get this working or if you know a better way let me know:

```
const errors = [{404: Error404}, {500: Error500}];
errors.forEach(error => {
        store = createStore(reducers, { page: { errors: error.key } });
        ...rest of the code
      })
```

so when I say error.key I want that to be 404 first iteration, and 500 second (numeric) that is set to the errors property.  I'll also want to get the value for each of those literal props (e.g. Error500) at some point in my forEach as well.

Comment: Why are you using an array of objects with different keys, instead of a single object with all the keys?

Comment: good question :) . Let me update it

Comment: I put it back to an array but what were you thinking about @barmar

Comment: I was thinking `errors = {404: Error404, 500: Error500}`

Comment: Your design is an unfortunately common anti-pattern.

Comment: anti-pattern: you mean using forEach or using an array with literals?  I want to understand so I can improve in it

Comment: right and how were you going to iterate the `{404: Error404, 500: Error500}`

Comment: >I've been in the computer industry since about 1979 :) . You must know Uncle Bob or of him then :P

Comment: The anti-pattern is the array of single-property objects where the keys are all different, instead of a single object. You can iterate over an object with `for (key in object)`.

Comment: thanks much @barmar I'll look at refactoring to improve on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Object.keys()` function to get all the keys of the object, then get the first element of that.

```
const errors = [{
  404: Error404
}, {
  500: Error500
}];
errors.forEach(error => {
  var key = Object.keys(error)[0];
  var val = error[key];
  store = createStore(reducers, {
    page: {
      errors: key
    }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for..in` loop within `.forEach()` to get the property of the object

```
const errors = [{ 404: "Error404" }, { 500: "Error500" }];
errors.forEach(error => {
  let key; for (key in error) break;
  store = createStore(reducers, { page: { errors: key } });
        // ...rest of the code
});
```